# Calling a function inside Jquery on click works first time on page load and afterwards does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to popup a modal on the click of a button, the modal plugin is called iziModal. I am doing this inside of a WordPress page, after the page loads it works on the first try but when I close the modal and click the button again the modal does not pop out but the alert function works
Here is my code below

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.modal-btn', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Am here");
    $mentorId = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
    jQuery('input[name="mentorId"]').val($mentorId);
    jQuery("#modal-popup").iziModal('open');
});

jQuery(document).on('closing', '#modal-popup', function (e) {
    jQuery('#modal-popup').hide();
    jQuery('.iziModal-overlay').hide();
});
```

Comment: The `iziModal('open')` method might not just toggle the `display: none` to `block` or whatever. If there is a open method, there should be a close method, sth like `iziMethod('close')` use that and see if it helps

Comment: I tried that too, the close method does not remove the modal from the page, so the only way i  had to remove the modal was to hide it using jQuery hide method. I am using jQuery instead of $ because the jquery plugin that wordpress uses, can only work with my code if i use jQuery. But if i add an external jquery using cdn and switch to $ instead of jQuery. it works

Comment: `jQuery`is equal to the use of `$` there might be other plugins/ frameworks in your wordpress theme that use the `$` though, so using the `jQuery` might be safer to avoid conflicts. That being said `jQuery('#modal-popup').iziModal('close')` should work

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```js
jQuery(document).on('closing', '#modal-popup', function (e) {
    $('#modal-popup').iziModal('close');
});
```

Comment: are you  remove  ```jQuery('#modal-popup').hide(); ``` from code when you try it  also try to change  event   (closing  to  closed)

Comment: Yes i remove the hide function and used the iziModal('close') and i have changed the closing to closed it still does not work. But when i switch from the jquery plugin wordpress is using to an external jquery cdn it works perfectly but some of the wordpress plugins that depends on the jquery plugin that wordpress uses, stops working because i switched the jquery

Comment: did you use `$('#modal-popup').iziModal('close');` or `jQuery('#modal-popup').iziModal('close');` as i suggested in my comment to your question ? There might be conflicts with other plugins using the `$`.